# How to create a datatype to hold 200+ digit long numbers in C?

Tags: c, types

OK,so I am trying to solve this problem: http://www.spoj.pl/problems/FCTRL2/

And using what I know about c, I have come up with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
long double factorial(int);
int main() 
{
    long double num[100], fact[100];
    int i = 0, ex;
    scanf("%d", &ex);
    for ( i = 0; i < ex; i++ )
    {
        scanf("%lf", &num[i]);
    }
    i = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ex; i++ )
    {
        fact[i] = factorial(num[i]);
        printf("%.0lf\n", fact[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
long double factorial(int num)
{
    long double onum, fact;
    int i;
    fact = 1;
    onum = num;
    for ( i = 1; i < onum; i++ )
    {
        fact = fact * num;
        num--;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

The problem is that long double is not long enough to hold values as long as 100! So, how can I create a datatype that can hold this large  value?

Comment: And CanSpice, how in the world did you get the formatting correct? I have been trying for last 10 minutes without luck. Thanks for fixing! :)

Comment: just put 4 spaces in front of each line.  The easy way is to select your code and then pick the `{}` button.

Comment: @CanSpice , Thanks. I feel dumb. Anyway, you just saved lot of my time and more importantly, many man-seconds that otherwise would have been wasted in fixing my future questions!

Comment: Does SPOJ accept `<conio.h>` nowadays? ?!?!?!

Comment: @pmg No. It does not accept conio.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular problem, GMP is indeed an overkill.

In fact, even the struct presented by Carl Norum, while useful and more general, contains more than what you will need. In particular, since all factorials are positive integers you don't need to worry about the sign.

Also, it's not necessary to implement addition, subtraction, or even general multiplication. You only need to worry about multiplying one of these "bignums" by an integer, which isn't too hard.

Here's a stub for the multiplication operation

```
void multiply( mybignum bn, int factor ) {
  // for each of the digits in 'bn'
  // multiplies 'factor' by the particular digit 
  // adds the previous remainder and stores
  // the new carry value
}
```

Comment: Rings some bells in head. I will try this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is no native data type that can hold numbers that large.  Check out the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/).

GMP might be a little overkill for your particular problem, but it will get the job done.  You could also write your own little arbitrary precision library to do it.

Edit - an example bignum type:

```
struct mybignum 
{
    int length;
    int sign;
    int digit[200];
};
```

You can just implement the grade-school algorithms for addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc. using that structure, and presto - 200-digit number support.

Comment: But it is external. While I can use something like this in a project of mine, the above code has to be complied on online server and there is no way to add a full external library there. Any way to do this in C?

Comment: @Ishan - if you can't use the library, you need to write your own.  Something small enough to fit the source limit for that problem and that will still be fast enough to do 100 multiplications shouldn't be that bad.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I will have to do that.