# c - data type for a very long number

Tags: c, types

I am working on the following problem of SPOJ ,

http://www.spoj.com/problems/ARITH/

It is said that the number should contain atmost 500 digits , what is the appropriate datatype for a number with maximun 500 digits

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a datatype to hold 200+ digit long numbers in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436007/how-to-create-a-datatype-to-hold-200-digit-long-numbers-in-c)

Comment: yes , i used a string with 500 size , but for doing calculations  , when we convert that string into a number , problem arrives ..

Comment: This may not be an effective solution. But, why not use arrays and do the operations from the last (n-1). Use temp variables (carry, borrow, etc. ) wherever needed. Again, this may not be an effective solution.

Comment: The constraints require for outputting intermediate values, which basically renders this question pointless. The answer is anyway `char[MAX_DIGITS + 1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use GMP library for multi-precision arithmetic and you will be sorted.

http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 4):

There is no builtin datatype to hold an integer of 500 digits. Thus, you have to come up with a way to store them in an array of bytes.

Get inspired by what http://gmplib.org/ does. In short, you will have to first store the digits somewhere:

```
struct Digit {
    size_t len;
    char   sign;
    char*  digits;
};
```

And then you must implement all the functions you need to work with such `Digit`:

```
void digit_init(struct Digit* d);
void digit_set(struct Digit* d, const char* digits);
void digit_add(struct Digit* a, struct Digit* b, struct Digit* result);
void digit_mult(struct Digit* a, struct Digit* b, struct Digit* result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built way to store that many digits as a number in c. That question is designed to make you do the arithmetic by other means (leaving the number as a string the whole time and dealing with small numbers of actual numbers at once). The question is way easier to do in Java (for example) because of BigInteger. But if you want to do it in c, I would look at how BigNum implementations work in general. This might help as a reference:

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/BigNum

Answer (score 0):

> For each multiplication, multiply the first number by each digit of the second number. Put the partial results one below the other, starting with the product of the last digit of the second number. Each partial result should be aligned with the corresponding digit."

Because of this constraint, there's no practical substitute to
  `char bignum[MAX_DIGITS+1]`;

**EDIT**  -- this was my original response; it's still useful, if one doesn't need to print intermediate results.

Since the emphasis is in *writing* the numbers down in base 10 and since the input is in base 10, I suggest using base ten derivative arrays -- Chars are a good candidate to study the long multiplication, but extending the base to 100, 1e4, 1e6 or 1e9 will make sense.

Base 100 would fit uint8_t or char, base 10000 would with uint16_t (while 16x16 ==> 32 multiplication is available even on most embedded processors); Doubles can hold exact values up to 2^53 -1, which would restrict each multiplicand practically to 1e6.

Working with e.g. base 1e8 allows storing 8 digits in (uint32_t) and it allows logically storing the result of multiplication in (uint64_t). It also allows printing the numbers readily without long division required for converting a base 2 bignum to decimal representation.

```
 struct big_int {
     uint32_t digits[MAX_DIGITS/8];
     unsigned int length;  //
     int sign;             // or possibly use int length and negative lengths
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such built-in function/type to perform arithmetic with such precision. Neither C nor C++. Nor STL. Nor boost for C++. Because you are going to submit it onto SPOJ, you can't link a custom library. As far as I know, if you insist on using C, and that you are doing a problem on SPOJ, you can only write your own routine or copy&paste.

Alternatively, try Java/Python that has builtin Big-Integer support whatsoever.

Long story short, no elegant way to achieve this, given the fact that you are going submit it on SPOJ.